# Webview not loading asset files second time it's attempted

Tags: android, webview, assets

I have a webview where I am loading local asset files in Android.  The first time that I open the app and load these files it works great.  Every subsequent time it just hangs.  If I delete the app data then it works again.  So it seems like something is getting 'cached', but I have cache disabled on the webview, and I even clear history, cache, etc before the loading the local assets to no avail.    Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - the newest Chrome Webviews have a function in them that create a file called 'webview_data.lock', and if you delete this file then everything loads correctly.  Found some documentation here https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwBrowserProcess.java and here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#web-data-dirs

Comment: what did you do to make it possible to load at the second time?